# Saving webpage as app

Tags: macos, google-chrome, web

I have a tiny web page, literally about 10 lines of pure HTML, not even any css or js. I'd like to save this as an app that I can use on my iMac. What would be the best way to do this?

It uses a feature of HTML5 that is currently only compatible with Chrome.

I've currently saved the html file in the Applications folder, so it appears in the list of applications. I would like it to appear in the dock though but when I click on it in the application list, it merely opens up a new tab in chrome. What I would like is for it to have its own icon etc, and appear to be standalone from chrome.

Is this easily doable?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com) to make site-specific browsers, but they are based on Safari or the original WebKit. Or you could save a script like this as an application in AppleScript Editor:

```
set u to "http://t.co/"
tell application "Google Chrome"
    repeat with w in windows
        set i to 0
        repeat with t in tabs of w
            set i to i + 1
            if URL of t is u then
                set active tab index of w to i
                set index of w to 1
                tell t to reload
                activate
                return
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
    make new window
    set URL of active tab of result to u
    activate
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to accomplish the behavior on a mobile platform. For example on iOS, you can place a bookmark of the site on the springboard. On a desktop system, HTML5 offline web application is a feature of the browser; not the operating system.

Comment: iOS has neither an Applications folder nor a Dock.

Comment: I know iOS doesn't have a dock, but he trying to mimic the behavior. On iOS, when you bookmark an to the springboard and launch it, it launch in full-screen mode. It doesn't show the URL bar from the browser.

Comment: I don't really need to hide the address bar etc, basically it would just be nice to have my web page always open in a new chrome window, with a custom icon that I can place in my dock. Thanks.